# What is the logic behind Unix's sort command?

Tags: linux, sorting, ubuntu, unix, logic

So I'm sorting a large file that has many lines of the form:

> <node_number>,<value>

The Unix command I'm using is very simple:

```
sort <file_name>
```

Here's *a part* of the output:

```
....
100009,0.000000
1000090,0.000000
100009,0.050510
1000093,0.000000
1000095,0.000000
1000095,0.000000
....
```

But why is:

```
1000090,0.000000
```

coming before:

```
100009,0.050510
```

even though:

```
100009,0.000000
```

was before it?
Shouldn't the order be:

```
....
100009,0.000000
100009,0.050510
1000090,0.000000
....
```

Why is this not the order in the output file? 
This weird order was there in many other parts of the file.

**Important Note:** I know there are options for the sort command to solve this issue. My intention isn't to find those options in the sort command. I just want to understand the logic behind the current sort output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I get your expected order when I try it on a Mac. It may depend on your local environment variables.

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C sort filename`